# Flutter: pass downloaded image to second screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a list if images download from internet. when you click on an image, it takes you to the image details screen. I want to pass the downloaded image itself to the second screen and avoid loading it again from internet. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used cached image provider plug in and it did the trick
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cached_network_image

When another image widget uses the same URL it will load from the cache instead of downloading it again.